# Data exchange between Java (Spring app) and C#

Tags: java, c#, spring, data-transfer, data-transfer-objects

I have a Spring web application and an standalone application written on C#. Only Spring application has an access to DB, so I want to implement data exchange between Java and C#. The data isn't large (100KB / Min or so). Application will be placed on the same machine. What is the best way to integrate a communication? Does Spring Framework has a module to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring certainly does have a module for doing this, it's called  [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/). You can define inbound and outbound channels/gateways and before the data comes in or out do any transformation on it needed to get it in the right format. Pretty standard functionality for doing enterprise integration.

Alternatively if that's too heavy weight you could expose a [`RESTful` webservice](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) in the spring application using the `@RestController` annotation and call that api from C# application. Another alternative would be to expose a `spring-ws` Web service in the spring application and write a Soap client that calls it in the C# application.

Comment: Spring Integration looks good. I have rest controllers in my app, but how can I secure rest controller so that only C# app could use it?

Comment: You can use [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) and configure each rest API to only be accessible by users with the ROLE_ADMIN role.